# Why is the doInBackground in this Android Async task not called

Tags: android

So I call this AsyncTask getValids with the method, Part I is logged but not part II

```
     Log.v("","entered main & 0 part I");
     String[] str_validsI = new getValids().execute("main").get();
     Log.v("","entered main & 0 part II");
```

Yet the first Log.v in it is never printed and none of the other funcitnos are called

```
protected String[] doInBackground(String... cat){
    Log.v("We are getting a HTTP Response","1");
```

Also the PreExecute IS called

```
protected void onPreExecute(){
    Log.v("","We're in pre execture");
    //this is the last function that is printed
}
```

This is the getValids class, doInBackground is never called and nothing is returned, why?

Does anyone see what is wrong and why it is not called?

```
public class getValids extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]> {
public List<String> retd = new ArrayList<String>();
private InputStream is = null;

//public List<String> getValids(String cat)
protected String[] doInBackground(String... cat){
    Log.v("We are getting a HTTP Response","1");
    String base_url = "http://universitytimes.ie/mobile/";
    String url = null;
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaaa".split("\\s*"));
    Log.v("We are getting a HTTP Response","2");
    if (cat.equals("main")){
        url = base_url;
    }else{
        url = base_url+cat;
    }
    try {
        // default HTTPClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        Log.v("We are getting a HTTP Response","The status " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        String str_valids = sb.toString();

        list = Arrays.asList(str_valids.split("\\s*,\\s*"));


    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

} //end do in bg

public void setResult(List<String> in){
    Log.v("We are getting a HTTP Response","1");
    retd = in;
}

public List<String> getResult(){
    return retd;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){
    Log.v("","We're in pre execture");
}

protected void onProgessUpdate(){}

protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result){
    setResult(result);
}
}
```

Comment: can u show calling syntax

Comment: Change to 
     `String[] str_validsI = new getValids().execute("main");` calling `get` will block the ui thread until task is finished making it no more asynchronous

Comment: I do in the first block of code `String[] str_validsI = new getValids().execute("main").get();
`

Comment: Rag, I know but that will do nothing to the doInBackground. I need to figure out why that is not working first then I'll refactor my code. DO you know why that is?

Comment: @bungleofsketches `doInbackground` is invoked after `onPreExecute`. Where do you invoke asynctask?

Comment: make sure you are starting the `AsyncTask` on the main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
String[] str_validsI = new getValids().execute("main").get();
```

With this:

```
String[] str_validsI = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) { // Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB = 11
   str_validsI = new getValids().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "main").get();
} else {
   str_validsI = new getValids().execute("main").get();
}
```

**Note:** That is not a good idea to use `AsyncTask`s with their `get()` method. Because you eliminate their nature and make them sync.

Comment: what on earth does that do? it fixed it! Thanks

Comment: If the preExecute is calling -as you said it is printing the log- that is the only reason. See this link for more info: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html